# How to send values to Ivar in method

Tags: objective-c, methods, ivars

new to Objective-C and keeping it very very simple I'm looking to understand one thing at a time... I set up a very simple class called student all it does is add two numbers trying to see how things pass into and back from methods) **I rewrote the code ==>> look at end to see the version that works **

If I have a method that has

```
@property (nonatomic) int firstNum; 
@property (nonatomic) int secondNum;
```

and I have an instance of my class called student I assign a value to `firstNum` like `student.firstNum = 100; student.secondNum = 77;` that is easy and the method adds them and sends the sum in a `return`

But in main I tried assigning it from an array and it did not work I tried

```
student.firstNum = [myIntegers objectAtIndex:0];
```

and

```
student.firstNum = [myIntegers objectAtIndex:i]; //using a for loop with i index
```

it says incompatible pointer to integer conversion

Here is the snippet from main I tried it's not complete it just is trying to set `firstNum` eventually I will also set up `secondNum` and send each pair to the method to get added together but for now I am stuck trying to get the firstNum assigned the value in `myIntegers[i]` to start

```
NSMutableArray *myIntegers = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSInteger i= 0; i <= 10; i++) {

    [myIntegers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]]; // this works up to here 

    student.firstNum = [myIntegers objectAtIndex:i]; // this does not work

}
```

I also tried `[i]`.

Here is my method:

```
- (int)addNumbers {

    int sum = self.firstNum + self.secondNum;
    return sum;
}
```

HERE IS WHAT WORKS : assuming I have a student object

.m

- (long)addNumbers:(NSNumber *)x :(NSNumber *)y {

  long sum;

  sum = [x integerValue] + [y integerValue];
  return sum;
  }

main

NSMutableArray *myIntegers1 = [NSMutableArray array]; 
   NSMutableArray *myIntegers2 = [NSMutableArray array];

```
    for (NSInteger  i= 0; i <40; i++) {

        [myIntegers1 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
        [myIntegers2 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
```

long sum = [student addNumbers:[myIntegers1 objectAtIndex:i] :[myIntegers2 objectAtIndex:i]];

```
        NSLog(@" The sum is %ld", sum);
}
```

Comment: You array consists of `NSNumber *`s, which are pointers to Objective-C objects. That's not a surprise: `NSArray` can only ever contain pointers to objects, and not primitives. Hance, `objectAtIndex:` returns a generic object pointer (`id`). `int` is a primitive, built-in C type. It's not a pointer. So, you can't assign the return value of `objectAtIndex:` to the property, because one is an `id` (i. e. a pointer to Objective-C object) and the other one is an `int`. You could, however, try converting the `NSNumber` object to an `int`. Read the documentation to find out how.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a properties of type `int`, but in your `for` loop, you are trying to assign them an `NSNumber`.

`NSNumber` is a simple container for a c data item and can hold `int`, `float`, `char`, `bool`, etc.

Change your loop to be like that:

```
for (NSInteger  i= 0; i <= 10; i++) {

    [myIntegers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];

    student.firstNum = [[myIntegers objectAtIndex:i] intValue]; // this 'extracts' the int value from the NSNumber

}
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense. I wanted to use something like

Comment: - (NSNumber *)addNumbers:(NSNumber *)x :(NSNumber *)y to pass in numbers I will try this to see if I can then use [[myIntegers objectAtIndex:i]